# What is name of this kind of graph/plot

Tags: data-visualization

Following graph is from [this article](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/epub/10.1161/CIRCULATIONAHA.119.044352):
[image]

It plots percent of participants showing improvement of different percent cut-off values (or more). This can be applied to a large number of situations where 2 drugs or interventions are given to 2 groups and some parameter is measured before and after study period.

A similar graph plotted for `iris` dataset is as follows:

[image]

Is there any general name for this type of plot/graph?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Although the means of construction of the `iris` data plot is unclear, both of the images look like empirical survival functions.  Compare to this plot in `R`: `library(data.table);
X <- as.data.table(iris[order(iris$Petal.Length), ]);
X[, step := 1/.N, by=Species];
X[, S := 1 - cumsum(step), by=Species];
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(X, aes(Petal.Length, S, color=Species)) + geom_step(size=1) + 
  geom_point(data=X[, .(S=min(S)), keyby=.(Species, Petal.Length)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this as an **empirical survival plot** for the corresponding variable, grouped by another factor. Note that the values plotted are simply $1 - \hat{F_n}(i)$ where $\hat{F_n}(\cdot)$ is the empirical cumulative distribution function.

Comment: +1. However, a close look at the last plot shows that's not quite how it is constructed.  Instead, only points of the form $(x, S(x))$ with $x\in\{0,1/2,1,\ldots,8\}$ have been plotted.

Comment: @whuber you’re right, I guess it might be more correct to say that the plot shows 1-ecdf(x), sampled at regular points and linearly interpolated.

Comment: Other names and more discussion at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485328/derivation-and-meaning-of-1-minus-the-cumulative-distribution

Comment: It will be very useful if you can add code (R or Python) to properly draw "Emperical Survival Plot".